# passing extra data to PHP through jQuery onclick

Tags: php, jquery, variables, post, onclick

I'm working on a quiz and would like to pass an additional variable to PHP when the user submits an answer (similar to a hidden input field). Here is my code when the user clicks "submit", I attempt to pass the variable 'test' in line 3:

```
function processQuestion(choice) {
         name = 'vote';
         $.post('poll_vote.php', {test: 2}, function() {
             alert(value);
         });
        getVote((val[0][quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice]]));
         if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#50D943'
             });
             $('#explanation').html('<strong>Correct!</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
             score++;
         } else {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#D92623'
             });
             $('#explanation').html('<strong>Incorrect.</strong> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
         }
         currentquestion++;
         $('#submitbutton').html('NEXT QUESTION &raquo;').on('click', function () {
             if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
                 endQuiz();
             } else {
                 $(this).text('Submit').css({
                     'color': '#fff'
                 }).off('click');
                 nextQuestion();
             }
         })
     }
```

In poll_vote.php, I have:

```
$vote = $_REQUEST['vote'];
$pollid = $_POST['test'];
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $pollid . '")</script>';
```

It appears 'test' is not being passed on. Ideally I'd like it to be recognized as "2" in PHP.

Comment: what happens if you print_r($_POST) in poll_vote.php? is it nested under something? It's showing up as getting posted for me under form data on a codepen.io - https://codepen.io/easement/pen/XNvWXp

Comment: @easement huh interesting, it prints "Array ( )" so somehow it's not pulling in any actual info.  it's not nested under anything - the only thing above $vote and $pollid is <?php